# Commits ahead on a Git cloned mirror repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, mirror

I'm using git for a while now, making messes and weird stuff, but now would like to achieve a good workflow.

This is the scenario, i got some repos on github that i want to push into only if i got a decent commit.

So i've cloned (--mirror) the github repositories on my workstation, so i can work on the mirrors from my laptops and locally on my workstation, without messing with github ("commit often, push once" as they say).

Everything is pretty nice, but a fundamental thing that i need to know before performing a push from a mirror to github is to know how many commits i'm ahead in the mirror (i know, git status doesn't work 'cause a mirror is also a bare type repo).

Simple schema of my workflow:

(git cloned) -> (git mirror on workstation) -> (github)

So how can i know how many commits i'm ahead in a cloned mirror repo ?

Comment: It's not clear that you need a mirror repo at all

Comment: In what sense Andrew ? My idea is to have a local shared repository that can push into github, so i was thinking to a local mirror. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Just rebase before you push ?  Unless you are actively using github to back up your work in progress you don't need an intermediate repository.

Comment: As you already figured out i'm using WIP commits. The idea is to share my local repository in LAN. An example: during the day i'm out working with my laptop. In the evening i can come home and push the commits on the workstation and work more comfortably. It's a matter of managing the changes between my machines, then of course rebasing before pushing to the real thing is a must.

Comment: You might be able to achieve what you want by adding a second remote to github and pushing directly to that.

Comment: Yeah you are right. No need for a mirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you checkout the mirror repository (at work or on your laptop). Add a second remote for github

```
git remote add github git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

When you finalize your commits, you can push them directly to github without messing with the mirror at all.

```
git push github master
```

Then when you want to push a WIP commit, just use push how you normally would and they will get pushed to your mirror instead. Then to see how far your master is ahead of github, you can do

```
git log github/master..master
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what Andrew C was suggesting. This one is a cleaner solution. You are both right, "i was doing it wrong".

Comment: Just for people reading the your answer, i tried out and works flawlessly. Bug before doing `git log github/master..master`, i had to pull github like this: `git pull github`.

Answer (score 1):

In the mirror repository, running `git rev-list --count FETCH_HEAD..HEAD` will show the number of commits by which the mirror is ahead of its origin. This is based on the last fetch you did in the mirror, but note that `git fetch` in the mirror will wipe out any changes committed to the mirror but not pushed to the mirror's origin.

You can see a more detailed picture with

```
git rev-list --count --left-right HEAD...FETCH_HEAD
```

which gives two numbers; the first is the number of commits on the current branch that are present in the mirror but not in the origin, and the second is the number of commits on the current branch that are present in the origin but not in the mirror (this will be positive if you reset a branch to an earlier commit, or rebase some commits that you already pushed).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution than my other answer: if you `git fetch` in the mirror, then all refs there are identical to the origin, so `git fetch && git status` in the clone of the mirror that you are working in will tell you what you need to know (because a recently updated mirror is an exact copy of its origin).

This also has the advantage that it works for any branch, not just `master`.

Comment: Good point, but the fact that `git fetch` wipes out every commit on the mirror is kind of a problem. I will probably commit changes from various machines into the mirror on the main workstation.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the mirror repository?

Comment: I want to use the mirror as a shared repository between my machine in my LAN. And then to use it as a single node to push finally to github, when i'm happy with my commits.